# Migrating Silverlight 4 to 5 - Generating references not reusing types - svcutil on binaries asking for certain SL4 binaries

Tags: types, reference, silverlight-5.0, ria, reusability

I have gone through a lot of posts on stackoverflow but couldnt get to this issue.
I recently migrated from SL4 to SL5 which in turn upgraded wcf ria to v1sp2.

Note : All binaries referenced now are v5.0.5.0, but System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client(web).dll is still version 2.0.5.0 (got with RIA).

After this generating of service references for my wcf service is not able to reuse types in referenced assemblies - its regenerating types causing ambiguous reference.

Using svcutil command to test the binary which contains the types is asking for SL4 version of System.Windows which is not available and thus failing.

```
svcutil /t:code http://localhost:9357/Service1.svc /r:binarywithtypes.dll
```

Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So few questions:

1. I am assuming that the reason its asking for SL4 binary is because some dependent assembly is still SL4. And from above reference it could be System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll.
   So where can I find v5.0.5.0 of this binary? (ria sp2 still gives v2.0.5.0)
2. Or is there some other reason that generating of references is not able to recognise types in referenced assemblies after moving to Silverlight 5?
3. Any other way I can generate references re-using already referenced types?

Note:Things used to work perfectly fine in SL4!

[UPDATE]:Command line tool slsvcUtils is working fine(while VS2010Sp1 is broken) and is able to reuse referenced types.
For others reference, slsvcutils usage:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil.exe" /language:cs /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 /n:*,<namespace> http://localhost:9357/Service1.svc /r:bin\debug\<slDllWithTypes.dll> /r:"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\system.windows.dll" /out:"Service References\Reference.cs" /enableDataBinding /config:temp.ClientConfig
```

Comment: I have the same problem, in VS12 the classes are generated multiple times in VS10 everything works (SL5). Now I always have to use VS10 to update the web service references... Did you find a solution to update it directly in VS12?